# django - get the id of just updated record

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

On my Django app I'm doing an update like this:

```
r = Mycords.objects.select_related().filter(name=r_name).update(title=r_title, message_body=r_message)
```

I need to get the id of just updated record so I can use it somewhere else on the code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoah.

Firstly, if this is just a single record, you should use `get` rather than `filter`.

Secondly, what's `select_related` doing in there?

Thirdly, all the updated records are in `r`. So you can access their IDs from there.

Comment: I think I copied that code from some place without thinking much how it works, but it works. My bad. What if I have for example multiple criteria to search for like update where "firstname= r_firstname" and "lastname = r_lastname" before I do an update can I still use "get" for that?

Comment: As long as you're sure that the combination of criteria will result in a single record being returned - otherwise Django will raise a MultipleObjectsReturned exception.

Comment: I got out my Django book and looks like you can do an update with a "get" but also with "update" (if you want to edit multiple records in bulk). I would still like to know how would I get the id of the last inserted records using the "update" instead of "get".

Comment: OK,I eliminated the select_related and used "get" instead of "update". Then I used r.id to get the id. Worked like a charm. Thank you!